# Is there a way to "merge" a virtual folder and a real one in evolution?

Tags: evolution, imap

As I understand Evolution mixes two kinds of folders in its mail folders pane:

- real folders (that exist on the server)
- virtual folders (e.g. messages marked for deletion are grouped in a virtual "Trash" folder, messages it thinks are spam in a virtual "Junk" folder...).

Every other mail client (and webmail system) has real folders for both examples, so in every IMAP account configured in Evolution I have two trash folders, two spam folders... Is there a way to tell Evolution it should "merge" them?

Answer (score 1):

From the OP:

> Seems like this is an [old](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=206061) and [debated](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evolution/+bug/13983) issue.